# jqGrid(?) triggers dropdown of datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid, and above it some other controls. The first one of these other controls is a jQuery UI datepicker.

My problem is: When tabbing along in the grid, the cursor in the grid works as expected, it selects the next cell, however, the datepicker (completely outside the grid) keeps getting dropped down!

Is there a way of preventing this drop down?

The Grid definitions (some cols removed because of the size)

```
    $("#dagbok_grid").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: [
            'Kr',
            'Annat dokument',
            'Region', ],
        colModel: [
          { name: 'Kronika', index: 'Kronika', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', editable: true },
          { name: 'AnnatDokument', index: 'AnnatDokument', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { maxValue: 50} },
          { name: 'Region', index: 'Region', width: 65, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
        ],
        cellEdit: true,
        cellsubmit: "clientArray",
        sortname: 'Datum',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        shrinkToFit: false,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        height: 400,
        caption: 'theGrid'
    });
```

Part of the view, including the datepicker:

```
<form id="kritera_form" action="">
    <fieldset id="kriteria">
        <legend>Urval</legend>

        <div id="col1" class="kolumn">
            @Html.Label("lblFrom", "From")
            <br />
            @Html.TextBox("txtFrom", null, new { tabindex = 1 })
            <br />
            <br />
```

The datepicker:

```
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker();
    $("#txtFrom").datepicker("setDate", -30);
```

**Edit: The complete colmodel:**

```
        colModel: [
          { name: 'a', index: 'a', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', editable: true },
          { name: 'b', index: 'b', width: 30, formatter: 'checkbox', edittype: 'checkbox', editable: true },
          { name: 'c', index: 'c', width: 70, formatter: 'date', editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { dataInit: function (elem) { $(elem).datepicker(); } } },
          { name: 'd', index: 'd', width: 65, editable: true, editrules: { time: true} },
          { name: 'e', index: 'e', width: 80, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'f', index: 'f', width: 100, editable: true },
          { name: 'g', index: 'g', width: 80, editable: true },
          { name: 'h', index: 'h', width: 80, editable: true, editrules: { maxValue: 50} },
          { name: 'i', index: 'i', width: 120, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'j', index: 'j', width: 200, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'k', index: 'k', width: 70, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'l', index: 'l', width: 25, editable: false },
          { name: 'm', index: 'm', width: 70, editable: true, editrules: { integer: true, maxValue: 999999 }, formatter: formatPosition, unformat: unformatPosition },
          { name: 'n', index: 'n', width: 25, editable: true, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: chkLongitudTecken} },
          { name: 'o', index: 'o', width: 80, editable: true, editrules: { integer: true, maxValue: 999999 }, formatter: formatPosition, unformat: unformatPosition },
          { name: 'p', index: 'p', width: 80, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
          { name: 'q', index: 'q', width: 100, editable: true, editrules: { maxValue: 50} },
          { name: 'r', index: 'r', width: 65, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' },
        ],
```

It seems like an event is sent to the datepicker when entering the columns with 'select'. It only occurs when using the tab-key in the grid, not when mouse-clicking.

I've changed the colnames to make it easier.

Comment: The current code don't include the most important part of your question: the call of jQuery UI Datepicker. Which options of Datepicker you use?

Comment: I have added the initialization. I'm not using any options at all, just defaults.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It should be some additional conditions which are important to reproduce your problem and which you don't described in the question. If you want I can post you link to the demo which corresponds your description, but which has no described problem.

Comment: Thanks! I've investigated further into the problem. I'm quite new to jQuery and the components, so I'm not sure how to go about it. It seems like the grid fires an event when entering a column with a select formatter and edittype. I can catch the event in the datepicker source, but the callstack does not let be go back far enough. Columns like these... { name: 'Kalla', index: 'Kalla', width: 80, edittype: 'select', editable: true, formatter: 'select' }